# opencl skipping data during operation on struct

Tags: python, opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

I have a custom `struct` on which I want to do an operation to reduce the field `scalar1` on all my structs. It is a very straightforward operation. It seems the subtraction is happening, but OpenCL does the operation on the wrong data. This is an MWE that can probably execute on your computer.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.tools
import numpy as np


kernelSource = """
__kernel void decreaseScalarFieldBy(__global myStruct *a, float delta)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
        a[gid].scalar1 -= delta;
}
"""

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
device = context.devices[0]

myStruct = np.dtype(
    [("vector1", cl.cltypes.float4),
     ("scalar1", cl.cltypes.float)])
name = "myStruct"
_, c_decl = cl.tools.match_dtype_to_c_struct(device, name, myStruct)
myStruct_dtype = cl.tools.get_or_register_dtype(name, myStruct)

program = cl.Program(context, c_decl + kernelSource).build()

N = 10
HOST_struct = np.empty(N, dtype=myStruct_dtype)
HOST_struct["vector1"] = np.array([cl.cltypes.make_float4(1, 0, 0, 0)]*N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float4)
HOST_struct["scalar1"] = np.ones(N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float)
TARGET_struct = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=HOST_struct)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=TARGET_struct, src=HOST_struct)

program.decreaseScalarFieldBy(queue, (N,), None, TARGET_struct, np.float32(0.5))

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=HOST_struct, src=TARGET_struct)
queue.finish()

print(HOST_struct)
```

And here's the output, which has the subtraction all shifted, which ends up subtracting inside the `vector1` field?

```
[((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 0.5) ((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 1. )
 ((1. ,  0. , -0.5,  0. ), 1. ) ((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 1. )
 ((0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 1. ) ((1. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.5), 1. )
 ((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 1. ) ((1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0. ), 1. )
 ((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 0.5) ((1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ), 1. )]
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this code?
I've tried separately with `float` and `float4` and they both work perfectly when outside a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of memory alignment was unknown to me.
From the OpenCL 1.2 [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), chapter 6.1, we learn that types have to be align on a 2^X. My struct is thus misaligned because it has a size of 36Bytes. `sizeOf(float4) = 16 Bytes`, `sizeOf(float) = 4 Bytes`.

However, `numpy` aligns arrays by default, but **NOT** in the same way as OpenCL does. Thus, the `struct` has to be matched to OpenCL alignment. This is the job of

```
_, c_decl = cl.tools.match_dtype_to_c_struct(device, name, myStruct)
```

The problem is that in my code, the new redeclared struct was omitted with the `_`. What needs to be done is to take the new redeclared `struct` and overwrite our old `numpy` declaration.

```
myStruct = np.dtype(
    [("position", cl.cltypes.float4),
     ("direction", cl.cltypes.float4),
     ("weight", cl.cltypes.float)])
name = "photonStruct"
myStruct, c_decl = cl.tools.match_dtype_to_c_struct(device, name, myStruct)
myStruct_dtype = cl.tools.get_or_register_dtype(name, myStruct)
```

Now everything works fine.